# Count items in list and make it a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am trying to generate a dictionary from the list

```
names = ['tango', 'bravo', 'tango', 'alpha', 'alpha']
```

The result is supposed to look like this:

```
{'tango': 2 , 'bravo': 1 , 'alpha': 2}
```

How would I be able to do that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is exactly what a `Counter` is for.

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter(['tango', 'bravo', 'tango', 'alpha', 'alpha'])
Counter({'tango': 2, 'alpha': 2, 'bravo': 1})
```

You can use the `Counter` object just like a dictionary, because it is a child class of the builtin `dict`. Excerpt from the docs:

> class Counter(__builtin__.dict)
>   Dict subclass for counting hashable items.  Sometimes called a bag
>   or multiset.  Elements are stored as dictionary keys and their counts
>   are stored as dictionary values.

edit:

As requested, here's another way:

```
>>> names = ['tango', 'bravo', 'tango', 'alpha', 'alpha']
>>> d = {}
>>> for name in names:
...     d[name] = d.get(name, 0) + 1
... 
>>> d
{'bravo': 1, 'tango': 2, 'alpha': 2}
```

Comment: is there another way to make it?

Comment: @uSEwrasd There are probably a hundred other ways, why?

Comment: im searching for a way without import anything which is not basic if possible, or does this import counts as something basic for the language?

Comment: @uSEwrasd I'd say using the standard library is pretty basic, but I added an import-less solution to my answer.

Comment: @uSEwrasd np, happy coding